Why doesn’t my Mac Chrome match Windows 10 Chrome?
I installed Mac Chrome on my Mac desktop running OS 10 and logged in using the same login as I do on my Windows 10 Chrome and for some reason the two Chrome applications don't look the same.
I was expecting to see the theme and shortcut icons I use on my Windows 10 Chrome to appear on my Mac Chrome. My question is how do I make my Mac Chrome look just like my Windows 10 Chrome?

What theme are you using? Which shortcut icons exactly? You need to be as specific as possible here.

The versions of applications on different operating systems (OS's) look different for a number of reasons. Two key differences:

Various libraries of the OS are used for the display of an application window. For example, the shape of the window, the controls used to scroll the window, and the file open and close dialogs are all provided by the OS.
Users of an OS have come to expect a specific look-and-feel for the graphic user interface (GUI), and the makers of the OS specify that appearance, such as Microsoft's guidelines. For example, Windows apps might use the menu path Tools > Settings, and Linux apps might use Edit > Preferences to display the same dialog.

If you want Chrome to look identical on both machines, run Windows in a virtual machine (VM) on the Mac, and install Chrome there, or vice versa.
